# Add 'expand' button to JTree node that has no children?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'd like to add the 'expand' button to my JTree's nodes to indicate that they are expandable. The catch is that they have no children until the user clicks on them (due to processing that happens in the background).

Is there any way I can set a node as a parent or having children without it actually having children?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible using your own [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) implementation overriding [`isLeaf()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#isLeaf%28%29):

> Returns true if this node has no children.

[Swing Tutorial: JTree](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html) explains it under *4.1 Dynamic Tree*.

Comment: I know it is an old question, but after implementing this solution, which works fine, I have an issue: when expanding this kind of nodes the node itself becomes selected, which is not the default behaviour in the other "normal" nodes. Any hint on that? Should I create a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Have a fake child/child count and replace it with real children using TreeWillExpandListener

Comment: I need to use you suggestion to implement lazy loading of tree nodes. But TreeWillExpandListener does not work if there is no child. What do you mean by "Have a fake child/child count"? Thanks.

Comment: Add a known, constant child to every node you expect to to be lazy loading, before attaching the listener. This will make the node look like it has children. In the listener, before the node expands check if this "fake" node is still there and replace it with the real ones if it is.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure this solution will work because doc of DefaultMutableTreeNode.add(MutableTreeNode newChild) method says : "Removes newChild from its parent and makes it a child of this node by adding it to the end of this node's child array.".            This means that one node can be added only to one parent.

Comment: What I meant is that you have to add the node, which you can definitely identify as "fake"