# Show 'expand' control on JTree nodes after children are removed?

Tags: swing, jtree

I have a [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) containing a subclass of [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html). I have only overridden `isLeaf()` to always return `true` because I lazily load the children when the node is expanded. Then, when the node is collapsed, I remove the children (firing the proper `treeNodesRemoved` event) because I have unsubscribed from updates from the server.

The problem is that after the user collapses a node and I remove the children, the stupid little expand circle disappears (but clicking that area still works to expand the node). How can I always show the expand control when the children have been removed?

Related: [Add 'expand' button to JTree node that has no children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472634/add-expand-button-to-jtree-node-that-has-no-children). Is adding a fake child the only way?

[image: Expand control disappears after collapsing]

Comment: Hmm, there's nothing obviously wrong with what you've done, my suggestion is to try different methods of notifying the model (and hence the tree) that the node has changed. For example, in your `TreeExpansionListener.treeCollapsed` method, you could call `defaultMutableTreeNode.removeAllChildren()` and then `defaultTreeModel.reload(defaultMutableTreeNode)`.

Comment: Can you give the detailed explanation of child removing. Why do you need this? "because I have unsubscribed from updates from the server" is not clear to me.

Comment: @MockerTim, When a node is expanded, I send a request to my server to fetch its children and subscribe to insert/remove/change events for its direct children. When the node is collapsed, I send a request to the server to stop receiving updates to its children. Then I remove all the children, since I didn't want to keep around nodes that could be stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it is I **add a fake child** and expansion listener when children are removed. When I get notification that the node with fake child is going to be expanded I replace the fake child with actual lazily loaded children.

This way the node always has children and expand control is always presented

Comment: That's what I ended up doing: Creating a fake child, and then removing it on treeWillExpand. I was hoping that isLeaf was sufficient, but apparently it's not.