# Prevent node selection on node expansion in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have created a `JTree` with some of its nodes being custom to show them as expandable although they don't have any children (yet). I have followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472634/add-expand-button-to-jtree-node-that-has-no-children/2472752) to implement that.

Why? I want do load the tree dynamically so when the tree gets expanded, I retrieve further information from the server and show it on the tree.

The problem I am experiencing is that when I expand one of these nodes, it becomes selected, which is not the default behavior for the default nodes (you can expand them without changing the tree selection).

How to solve this to prevent this node to become selected on expansion?

Answer (score 4):

I don't get that problem with the code below. You must be doing something else that we can't guess without seeing your code. Try taking the code below and modify it to reproduce the problem you are seeing. By doing that, there is a great chance that you will find what you are doing differently and why you get that behaviour (see also [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)).

The code has been taken from [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

public class DynamicTree extends JFrame {

    public class OutlineNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
        private boolean areChildrenDefined = false;
        private int outlineNum;
        private int numChildren;

        public OutlineNode(int outlineNum, int numChildren) {
            this.outlineNum = outlineNum;
            this.numChildren = numChildren;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildCount() {
            if (!areChildrenDefined) {
                defineChildNodes();
            }
            return super.getChildCount();
        }

        private void defineChildNodes() {
            // You must set the flag before defining children if you
            // use "add" for the new children. Otherwise you get an infinite
            // recursive loop, since add results in a call to getChildCount.
            // However, you could use "insert" in such a case.
            areChildrenDefined = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
                add(new OutlineNode(i + 1, numChildren));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            TreeNode parent = getParent();
            if (parent == null) {
                return String.valueOf(outlineNum);
            } else {
                return parent.toString() + "." + outlineNum;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DynamicTree(5);
            }
        });
    }

    public DynamicTree(int n) {
        super("Creating a Dynamic JTree");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Container content = getContentPane();
        JTree tree = new JTree(new OutlineNode(1, n));
        content.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300, 475);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that code the creation of new nodes is immediate since it is just an example. On my case this "sub-node creation" requires a call to the server which can take from half second up to some seconds depending on the data to retrieve.

However I realized now that overriding the method `getChildCount()` and returning a fake number of children (1 in my case) while I retrieve the server data, and rebuilding the node when got it, fixes my problem.

My guess: it was expecting to expand some number of nodes but when doing that find that has 0... something weird

+1

Comment: @spuas It sounds like lazy loading is what you need (currently tackling a similar problem). Here are some links for reading: http://www.jroller.com/Thierry/entry/swing_lazy_loading_in_jtree http://www.koders.com/java/fidD67C269743C2E91D691FCD30D5A66660F3226744.aspx?s=BasicNode